# How to Drag and Drop files onto VB6 app?

Tags: vb6

I am trying to create an VB app that can install android apk from PC. In this way, when I want to install apk ,I prefer dropping an apk from explorer to app. But I don't know how to do this . I am new to VB6. Please help me !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Forgive me , your majesty !
    There is no code ! Thank you ..

Comment: This question is not definitely unclear. It means you can't, you don't know how to, You are getting quite away of thinking on it.

Comment: I agree with the OP : the question is quite clear, although maybe not as fancy worded as wished for

Comment: @Hrqls There isn't a "sorry, this is not a 'plz giv me teh codez' website" close reason. This is the best approximation that you can get. Either that or "This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself." It isn't really about fancy wording, it's about showing some effort toward solving the problem yourself.

Comment: @CodyGray : sometimes you have to read between the lines and notice that this is a new vb user. he asks how to capture the filename of a file being dropped on the form. that was clear from his question. he didnt post any code, but probably he didnt have any clue on which event to use or even that he could use an event for it. If i would have posted this question (with the same knowledge as the OP) then i would have used more words and probably included 2 pictures to show drag&drop, and it probably would not have been closed. .. you are right about the effort which was put into the question :)

Comment: @CodyGray : maybe we should have a closing-tag which states "there was not put enough effort in the question", preferably including some links to how a question would ideally look like .. that would be more first-time-user friendly for sure :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To capture the filenames of the files being dropped on a form you can use the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_OLEDragDrop(Data As DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  Dim intFile As Integer
  With Data
    For intFile = 1 To .Files.Count
      Print Data.Files.Item(intFile)
    Next intFile
  End With 'Data
End Sub
```

This will print the filenames of the files on the form. Just change the Print statement to your own code to install the apk

**[EDIT]**

I forgot to mention that you have to set the OLEDropMode of the form to 1 - Manual otherwise you can't drop anything on the form

Comment: Thank you for answering ! I am very quite new to VB. My problem is can't dropping files on form ! Mouse pointer state is (\) not allow dropping files on form! Please help me .. Thank you for your kindness !

Comment: Thank you ... So much ,, This code is definite what i wanted ! :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the OLEDropMode of the form should be set to 1 (Manual)

Comment: Yes, But I did it. Thank you so much Sir ! You are so skillful ! :D